# Unable to get sound out of my bluetooth speaker (JBL pulse 2)

Tags: 16.04, gnome, sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I try to get my conputer sound get out from my bluetooth speaker without success

About my system :
- Ubuntu 16.04 (gnome)
- kernel : 4.13.0-32-generic

Problem :
- Bluetooth logo appear on top right corner of my screen
- I find my speaker in bluetooth devices list and pair it with my computer
- pairing work well but sound get out from integrated speakers of my computer (not from my bluetooth speaker)

What i've already tried :
- Go to Setting > sounds > Output but i've only integrated speakers in the list
- Install pavucontrol > my bluetooth speaker doesn't appear- Install blueman to pair my bluetooth speaker as "headset" and "audio synchronie".when i right click on my bluettoth speaker in blueman, "audio profile" seem to be empty.

Some logs :

```
uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth Linux fabien-sabre-15 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b59e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c019 Logitech, Inc. Optical Tilt Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    2.689308] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.689318] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.689321] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.689322] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.689325] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.740371] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.740373] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.740373] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.740384] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.740384] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.740385] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.740402] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.740411] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    2.740412] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    2.740412] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    2.740413] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    2.749017] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f00
[    2.753862] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
[    2.897596] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[    4.959709] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.959710] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.959712] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   15.249510] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.249515] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.249519] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    0.098162] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.144516] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    2.753862] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
[    2.765858] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.610311.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.897596] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
bluetooth             544768  39 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth


sudo service bluetooth status
[sudo] Mot de passe de fabien : 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since jeu. 2018-02-08 21:22:33 CET; 20min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 986 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─986 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

févr. 08 21:22:33 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: Not enough free handles to register service
févr. 08 21:22:33 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: Sap driver initialization failed.
févr. 08 21:22:33 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
févr. 08 21:22:33 fabien-sabre-15 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
févr. 08 21:22:43 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 08 21:22:43 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 08 21:22:56 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.105 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
févr. 08 21:22:56 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.105 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
févr. 08 21:22:56 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
févr. 08 21:22:58 fabien-sabre-15 bluetoothd[986]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_B8_69_C2_84_D4_7B/fd0: fd(22) ready


dpkg -l | grep blue
ii  bluez                                   5.37-0ubuntu5.1                            amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                              5.37-0ubuntu5.1                            amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd                             5.37-0ubuntu5.1                            amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64         3.18.2-1ubuntu2                            amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth                         3.18.2-1ubuntu2                            amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  indicator-bluetooth                     0.0.6+16.04.20160526-0ubuntu1              amd64        System bluetooth indicator.
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                     5.37-0ubuntu5.1                            amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64              3.18.2-1ubuntu2                            amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth             1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7                           amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server


sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If an expert have any idea...

Thank's in advance